# How can I implement double buffering with an Arduino UNO?

Tags: arduino-uno, display

I am creating a tiny game on my Arduino UNO with an Adafruit ST7735 1.8" TFT / SD breakout. I am performing screen operations using the built-in TFT-library.

The problem is screen flickering. Even though I take care to prepare data and minimize the time between clearing the screen and writing the new stuff to it, the screen "refresh()" is significant. I heard someone mention something called double buffering, so I read a bit up on it, but I am frankly clueless on how to implement it on an Arduino UNO.

Is it possible to implement double buffering on an Arduino UNO to prevent screen flickering, and if so, how?

Libraries used:

```
#include <TFT.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>
```

The screen is "cleared" like this:

```
screen.background(0,0,0);  // Clear it
screen.text(buf, 10, 25);  // Write new stuff
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're already preparing the next screen's-worth of data before you clear the screen, then double buffering won't help. In that case, the time taken to re-write the screen data is what causes the flicker, and the only way to improve it is to write the screen faster. If the software is to blame, it will be in screen.text(). If the software is already driving the hardware as fast as the hardware will go, then that's the best you can do.

Double-buffering would let you prepare the next screen while the currently-prepared one is loading (and will require interrupt-driven I/O to do it). The result would be more screen refreshes per unit time, but it doesn't sound like that is your problem.

One easy experiment to try is to not clear the screen before you re-write it, if that is possible to do. Then your next screen will overlay the current screen with (we hope...) no blanking period. That might prevent the blinking.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I implement double buffering with an Arduino UNO?

Full screen [double buffering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering) (aka [off-screen bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347367/whats-concept-of-off-screen-bitmap)) for an ST7735 (128 x 160 x 16 bit color) would require 40 Kbyte. With only 2K byte SRAM on the Arduino Uno double buffering is not possible.

Some of the flickering is due to the Arduino core unoptimized SPI protocol and the graphics library. They could be optimized to reduce some of the flickering.

Please see the Cosa [ST7735](https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Cosa/tree/master/libraries/ST7735) driver and [SPI](https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Cosa/blob/master/cores/cosa/Cosa/SPI.hh) support for examples of high speed inter-leaving SPI transfer and graphics optimizations.

Smaller mono-chrome screens (such as ST7565) can be supported with double buffering. An example is the Cosa [OffScreen Canvas](https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Cosa/blob/master/libraries/Canvas/Canvas/OffScreen.hh) that can be used to create a bitmap that is transfered to the screen in a [single operation](https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Cosa/blob/master/examples/LCD/CosaST7565/CosaST7565.ino#L157).

Cheers!

Comment: Arduino Due has 40k RAM to spare, but I don't see how that solves the issue of the screen flickering as you will still need to transfer the data to the display controller, meaning you will still have to watch the screen slowly update and for complex contents the screen will spend much more time while updating is in progress than it will be displaying the desired final contents.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Most Arduino graphics libraries use pixel level update and draw directly to the display memory. They do not use a off-screen bitmap and then transfer in a single operation. The transfer can be synchronized with the display to avoid flickers. See chap. 9.11 in the ST7735 datasheet, https://www.displayfuture.com/Display/datasheet/controller/ST7735.pdf

Comment: Interesting, thank you very much for responding, I want to investigate the possibilities of of some sort of partial buffering / transfer batching.
It's a shame that none of the popular controllers (ST7735, ILI9341, SSD1963 etc.)  support indexed 8-bit color palettes. 256 colors is more than enough for most embedded applications, and having 8-bit pixel values would mean that each of the controllers I mentioned can already store at least two full sets of image data.

Answer (score 1):

To add to previous answers:

Double-buffering is an approach where you *write to the actual device* - but in an off-screen area. Then you switch to the new area in a single instruction, indistinguishable to the naked eye, rather than clear the visible area and write while it's still being displayed.

This requires that the *device* has extra memory to support the two areas: on-screen and off-screen. Absent that extra memory, then the best that you can do is pre-calculate as much as possible, and write to the screen as fast as possible.